# auto showing and hiding navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to implement a auto show and hide navigation menu. I'm not sure how I would implement this idea. The idea I'm wanting is so the navbar slips away out of site above the website and when the cursor hovers over the top the nav bar appears. (A better example is (if you own a Mac) the idea comes from the Dock when auto hidden).

Would I use a .CSS transition or a JQuery/Javascript to implement this.

Heres the navbar I'm working with,

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #a137a7;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    opacity: .8; 
 
 
}

li {
    float: left;

}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

/* Hover color */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #732878;
}

.footer {
  color: #fff;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
  padding: 0.70em 0.75em;
  background: #000;
  font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  top: 490px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  opacity: .7; 
}
```

```html
<nav>
        
        <ul>
    
        
         <li><a href="/"><img class="img-responsive2"       
       src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/Ywiod4uar/fb-icon.png"></a></li>
           
         <li><a href=/""a target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive2"       
       src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/liGockmkp/twitter-256.png"></a></li>
       
       <li><a href="/"><img class="blog"       
       src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/i0Nocny7l/blog-icon.png"></a></li>

<li><a href="/" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 
'toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,height=620,width=700'); return false;"><img class="img-responsive2"       
       src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/UrWocm53a/games-icon.png"></a></li> 
       
  
  <li style="float:right"><a href="/"><img class="img-responsive2"       
       src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/vHdockmf2/tinychaticon.png"></a></li>
       
         <li style="float:right"><a href="/"><img class="img-responsive2"  src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/4Yxocknow/refresh.png"></a></li>
       
        <li style="float:right"><a href="/"><img class="img-responsive2"       
       src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/HPzod3sz1/pop-out-icon.png"></a></li> 
       
    <li style="float:right"><a href="/""a target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive2"       
       src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/nz3ocovr0/tumblr-follow-icon.png"></a></li>
       
      
        

</ul>
        </nav>
        <body>
```

Comment: Its also available in Windows and Linux also.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `nav` to slide up and down. See my code:

I've added a red border to the nav, so you can see it (for demo).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.hover').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('toggleNav');
  });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;  
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 175px;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}
nav:hover, nav.toggleNav {
  top: 0px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #a137a7;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  opacity: .8;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
/* Hover color */

li a:hover {
  background-color: #732878;
}
.footer {
  color: #fff;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
  padding: 0.70em 0.75em;
  background: #000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  top: 490px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  opacity: .7;
}
.hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/Ywiod4uar/fb-icon.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/" target="_blank">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/liGockmkp/twitter-256.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <img class="blog" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/i0Nocny7l/blog-icon.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 
'toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,height=620,width=700'); return false;">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/UrWocm53a/games-icon.png" />
      </a>
    </li>


    <li style="float:right">
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/vHdockmf2/tinychaticon.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li style="float:right">
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/4Yxocknow/refresh.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li style="float:right">
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/HPzod3sz1/pop-out-icon.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li style="float:right">
      <a href="/" target="_blank ">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/nz3ocovr0/tumblr-follow-icon.png " />
      </a>
    </li>



    /
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="hover">Hover here</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make navbar hover over page content. Like a place holder?

Comment: Thank you for this, much needed. Just one question in regards to browser support. I'm using this menu over a flash element on my website. The pop down menu  works perfectly in all browsers except Firefox.

Comment: Is it possible to add support to Firefox?

Comment: Sorry my mistake do it does appear the only thing that does not is the place holder that says 'Menu'.

Comment: under the flash element

Answer (score 0):

This Is An Example Of Your Requirement Please Try Once

```js
function myFunction(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coor;
  if(y<=50){
   document.getElementById("navBar").style.display = 'block';
  }
  else{
  document.getElementById("navBar").style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function clearCoor() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.nav{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:#00ffff;
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<div onmousemove="myFunction(event)" onmouseout="clearCoor()">
<div class="nav" id="navBar"></div>

</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;  
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 175px;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}
nav:hover {
  top: 0px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #a137a7;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  opacity: .8;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
/* Hover color */

li a:hover {
  background-color: #732878;
}
.footer {
  color: #fff;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
  padding: 0.70em 0.75em;
  background: #000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  top: 490px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/Ywiod4uar/fb-icon.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/" target="_blank">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/liGockmkp/twitter-256.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <img class="blog" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/i0Nocny7l/blog-icon.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 
'toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,height=620,width=700'); return false;">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/UrWocm53a/games-icon.png" />
      </a>
    </li>


    <li style="float:right">
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/vHdockmf2/tinychaticon.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li style="float:right">
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/4Yxocknow/refresh.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li style="float:right">
      <a href="/">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/HPzod3sz1/pop-out-icon.png" />
      </a>
    </li>

    <li style="float:right">
      <a href="/" target="_blank ">
        <img class="img-responsive2" src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/nz3ocovr0/tumblr-follow-icon.png " />
      </a>
    </li>



    /
  </ul>
</nav>

<body>
```